# Where can I find the old version of the Mint app for iOS 4?

Tags: iphone, applications, ios-appstore, ios

I'm on a jailbroken iPhone 4 running iOS 4.3.5. There is still not an untethered jailbreak for iOS 5, so I am not able to upgrade yet.

Mint has gotten a bit ahead of themselves and released a new version of their iOS app that requires iOS 5. The old version supported on iOS 4, but it is no longer available. There has been [some talk on their support forum](http://satisfaction.mint.com/mint/topics/mint_for_older_iphone_3gs_running_ios_4_3_5) about the issue, but there doesn't seem to be a solution.

Where can I find the old version of the Mint app that supports iOS 4?

Comment: I have the same problem. I want to use Mint on my non-jailbroken 2nd generation iPod touch, which runs iOS 4.2.1. I had a copy of Mint 1.x for months, and used it happily. Then Mint released 2.0, which is not compatible with iOS 4.2.1. My copy of 1.x was summarily deleted from my iPod touch by iTunes when it synced my iPad 2 with Mint 2.0, and now I have no Mint to run on my older iPod touch.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is a untethered jail break for iPhone 4 for iOS 5.0.1 http://www.iphone4jailbreak.org/how-to-jailbreak-iphone-4-using-jailbreak-me-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, This is not possible due to current App Store limitations <del>unless someone else with a jail broken iPhone that you trust has a copy of it that you can grab</del>. One problem with dealing with the Apple App Store is that older versions are forever lost due to Apple's App Store polices. **We should be giving concerned feedback to Apple to address this issue too, not just the app developers.** So it looks like your best option if you need to have the Mint app, is to read up on the latest jailbreak, and insure your jailbreak path, then update your iPhone to the latest iOS, and then re-jailbreak it. The good news is that there is a untethered jailbreak for both iOS 5 and iOS 5.0.1 for the iPhone 4 as [referenced](http://www.iphone4jailbreak.org/how-to-jailbreak-iphone-4-using-jailbreak-me-tutorial.html) in my comment above.

Comment: This is not possible. Jailbreaking allows access to the physical file system and allows unsigned code to run on the device (like Cydia), but it does not circumvent Apple's protection scheme for apps found in the App Store. Apple binds purchases to devices authorized to run them. If you gave me Infinity Blade, for example, I could put it on my phone (even without a jailbreak), but it wouldn't run unless you authorize me device with your account. And that's probably no a feasible solution for 99.9% of people. Bypassing this protection is illegal and has no place within these walls.

Comment: Good point I did not realize that the app was tied to the  Apple ID also, I was thinking only   about a simple code signing check would be preventing the app from running.